# Как удалить идентификатор сессии из адресной строки?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

Подключаю bootstrap-5 на страницу  html:

```
<link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

это работало до некоторого момента.
Но внезапно файл bootstrap.css перестал подключаться. Посмотрел код страницы html и увидел:

```
<link href="/testCreator/css/bootstrap.css;jsessionid=D5D57331850ADD316532C1ECA0C140BA" rel="stylesheet">
```

При этом, если обновить страницу, файл подключается. Эффект наблюдается в нескольких браузерах.
Как удалить jsessionid из этого кода ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно дело в путях. Попробуйте прописать путь полностью `https://site.ru/css/bootstrap.css` замените `site.ru` на ваш домен.

Comment: Я не думаю, что это является решением. Файл bootstrap.css ведь подключается после F5 при тех же путях. Скорее, причина - в настройках thymeleaf+spring, только не знаю, в каких.

Answer (score 0):

действительно, если по совету Arcadiy отказаться от модификатора th:href="@{...}" и написать

```
<link href="/testCreator/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

вместо

```
<link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

то SID изчезнет из адресной строки.
Ошибка устранена, но её причина неизвестна.